# how do I run a function on a data set that is too large?

Tags: r, function, output, bigdata

I'm trying to perform a hierarchical cluster in R. The data set I'm using is only 1.4 mb. for some reason when I run the `dist()` function, I get the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 13.3 Gb

I only have 8Gb of ram on this pc and I haven't been able to find any approach that could allow me to get the distance results.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the output for a function that is larger than my ram capacity?

Comment: Only 1.4 MB but how many rows + columns ? Consider a different method; the issue here is that hierarchical clustering doesn't scale well.